# get numeric part of ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following element:

```
<div id="ITEM22"></div>
```

I can get the id like this:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

But how can I get just the numeric part of this if, i.e. **22** ?

EDIT: **ITEM** is always a prefix.

Comment: Downvote and close? Why? Seems clear enough to me.

Comment: Most things are a question of RTM... perhaps SO should be shut down because everything is bleeding obvious?

Comment: @markus: Ah, I see. I'll go through and vote to close *every single regex question on the site*, then. It's all just string manipulation, right? I bet I can break the naive solution to this problem with a simple change in data (hidden constraints of the problem).

Comment: +1, seems like a legit question.

Comment: @markus Even though its an easy question, it is still a question about programming. Other beginners searching out there will find the answer useful.

Comment: I'm sorry if this seems like an obvious question, but for someone like me with no formal training as a developer, I learn these techniques as they come...

Comment: No need to apologize, your question and future questions like it are fine.  If you ever wonder if a question fits here take a look at the FAQs: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you always have the prefix `ITEM` then you can

```
var numeric = this.id.replace('ITEM','');
```

and as @Felix mentions in the comments you can convert it directly to a usable number (*instead of just a string representation it*) by using the [+ unary operator <sup>MDC docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2b_%28Unary_Plus%29) instead

```
var numeric = +this.id.replace('ITEM','');
```

---

Additionally, i have changed the `$(this).attr('id')` to `this.id` since `this` already refers to the object you want and you can directly access its `id` attribute with `this.id`

Comment: +1 you can also easily convert it to a number with the unary `+`.

Comment: @Felix, wasn't sure if the OP really wanted it as a number or just that part of the string.. will add it though for more info..

Comment: It is always ITEM as a prefix.

Comment: I don't need it as a value. It will be parsed as an ID.

Comment: @santa, cool. Use any option that fits your requirements.. Just pointed them all out in case you wanted more flexibility.

Answer (score 17):

```
var thenumber22 = $(this).attr('id').match(/(\d+)/)[1]
```

Comment: Best way to do it. This way doesn't depend on ITEM. You can change the id text to anything and the JS will still work.

Comment: +1, but @silent1mezzo, it would fail if the prefix contained numbers though. (*nit-picking mode off*)

Comment: You could use .match(/(\d+)$/)[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
var whatYouWant = getNo($(this).attr('id'));

function getNo(stringNo)
{
    var parsedNo = "";
    for(var n=0; n<stringNo.length; n++)
    {
        var i = stringNo.substring(n,n+1);
        if(i=="1"||i=="2"||i=="3"||i=="4"||i=="5"||i=="6"||i=="7"||i=="8"||i=="9"||i=="0")
            parsedNo += i;
    }
    return parseInt(parsedNo);
}
```

Comment: That seems to be a lot more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: This gets the award for "Most Bloated Coding Solution Ever."

Comment: Because this is an awful way to do it.

Comment: Sometimes I really don't understand this site. "Give me a way to do this?" - If he said, "give me the most efficient way to do this", then I can understand down voting this answer.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between "Show me every possible way to do this" and "Show me some ways to do this, and explain the (dis)advantages of each option."

Comment: An error has slipped in there as well... `i=="6"| |i=="7"` should be `i=="6"||i=="7"`. No space between the two `||`

Comment: I sympathize with you slandau, your solution is verbose but it works.  But I guess in the face of multiple answers the voting works to separate the efficient answers from all possible answers.

Comment: I guess so, but I think purely upvoting the better answers achieves the same idea of separation. I think the downvote should be reserved for answers that do NOT answer the question, or that do NOT work.

Comment: Do be "fair", down voting means *this answer is not useful*. An answer can be not useful in various ways. But I agree with you, I normally reserver my down votes for questions that are really wrong...

Comment: This solution is extremely useful in a situation, when you receive payments by the LOC :)

Comment: It was not me who down-voted your answer. I appreciate any input. +1 to correct injustice. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="ITEM22"></div>

var id = $(this).attr('id');  
var numeric_part = id.replace(/[A-Z]+/, '');  //Output : 22
```

Answer (score 0):

This extracts digital part of a string using a **Regular Expression.**

`var numericPart = id.match(/\d+/);`